# How do I move a multidimensional array into another method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm having trouble solving the last part of a task. I'm getting the smallest number in the array, but when i move it to another method I get this in my print:

```
[[D@2a139a55
```

If i write this in my `main(String[] args) {` I get 0 which is correct.

```
public class Task05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] numbers = getArray();

        System.out.println("Smallest number in array is " + numbers);

    }

    public static double[][] getArray() {

        double[][] numbers = new double[25][25];
        double smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < numbers[row].length; column++) {

                if (smallest > numbers[row][column]) {
                    smallest = numbers[row][column];



                }

            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you mean by "carried out in a different method"? And what have you tried so far? Also you are not filling your array with values. In your `System.out.println`, you should use `smallest` instead of `numbers[row][column]`.

Comment: edited the question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: @KristofferNærland `getArray()` returns an *array* (!), that you then print. How do you expect that to print a single number?

Comment: @KristofferNærland Please remember to accept answers that you feel have answered your question! It helps others who come along later with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your array **to the method**. Right now, you are creating a new array in your `getArray()` method that has nothing in it!

What you have to understand is that even though your method is `Static`, your array is not! This means that you need to pass your array as a parameter into your method.

Also, the reason that you are getting that output is that you are passing your array to your print statement, not calling the getArray() method (which would also return the address at this point).

Inside your `getArray()` method, you actually don't need to or really want to create a second array. Think about it this way; what if your array was 1,000,000 elements? Would you really want to allocate another 1,000,000 elements simply to find the smallest element? No! This is extremely pricing on system resources. We'll just iterate through the array we have already created!

Based on the issue I presented above, you need to return the smallest number that you have found, not the address of the array! This means you need to change your return type to `double` and `return smallest`

```
 public class Task05 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double[][] numbers = getArray();

            System.out.println("Smallest number in array is " + getArray(numbers));

        }

        // Changed return type to double, instead of double[][]
        public static double getArray(double [][] numbers) {
            double smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            for (int row = 0; row < numbers.length; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < numbers[row].length; column++) {

                    if (smallest > numbers[row][column]) {
                        smallest = numbers[row][column];
                    }

                }
            }
            // Return the smallest number that you found
            return smallest;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create and initialize array
        int[][] x = {{1, 2, 0}, {4, 5, 6}};
        // call smallest method and print the value returned
        System.out.println("smallest is " + smallest(x));
    }

    // smallest method 
    // to find small element in array

    public static int smallest(int[][] x) {
        // suppose the first element is the small one
        int smallest = x[0][0];

        // iterate throgh array
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {

                // compare current element with smallest element
                // if current element is the small one then save it in smallest variable
                if (x[i][j] < smallest) {
                    smallest = x[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        // return smallest
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be beneficial to OP if you explain why his code doesn't work and why your approach is better, rather than just giving code. :)

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, posting uncommented code will probably not help much. The OP surely is interested in finding out what he did wrong.

Comment: [System.out.println("Smallest number in array is " + numbers);], here you printed the reference of the array not the array. I post this method to show you how just return one value. another thing is that you declared two array one in method main and other in getArray() method.